# "Профессор кислых щей"

Tags: фразеология

Скажите, пожалуйста, откуда пошла ироничная поговорка "профессор кислых щей" для обозначения много воображающих о себе недоучках? Подозреваю, что это из литературы, но не уверен.
Спасибо.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Так презрительно осаживают малограмотного  человека, вздумавшего рассуждать о вещах, в которых сам ни ухом ни рылом. Суди, мол, дружок, не выше сапога. В кислых щах ты, может быть, и разбираешься, а вещи серьёзные тебе недоступны. Впрочем, такая ли простая вещь – кислые щи?

Вот недавно знатоки русской старины выкопали любопытный факт: оказывается во времена Екатерины II в оранжереях русских вельмож выращивалось такое количество ананасов, что их квасили в бочках, а потом варили из них кислые щи. С тех пор немало ананасов было испорчено в попытках сварить из них мясной суп. И того невдомёк доморощенным профессорам, что кислыми щами в былые времена называли вовсе не суп, а напиток наподобие кваса. Вот как Николай Васильевич Гоголь завершает описание первого дня Чичикова в губернском городе NN:

“День, кажется, был заключён порцией холодной телятины, бутылкою кислых щей и крепким сном во всю насосную завёртку, как выражаются в иных местах обширного русского государства”.

Суп с квашеной капустой в бутылках, как известно, не подают. Так что тепличные ананасы, предназначенные для щей, мариновали (в бочонках, естественно, в чём же ещё можно было запасать продукты двести с лишним лет назад!), а потом готовили из них шипучий напиток “на семи солодах”, что-то вроде сидра.

Вкусно, должно быть, было…

Comment: Да! Я тоже читала, что кислые щи - это был газированный кисло-сладкий напиток из сквашенной капусты. Интересно было бы попробовать. Надо поискать в сети рецепт))

Comment: Идея! Если найдете - поделитесь!

Comment: Из Википедии.  http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CA%E8%F1%EB%FB%E5_%F9%E8
Ки́слые щи (кислые шти) — старинный русский медово-солодовый напиток, разновидность шипучего кваса. Представляют собой род медового кваса или, быть может, легкого солодового меда.
 Упоминает их и Пушкин в одном из черновиков, которые современные пушкинисты относят к «Евгению Онегину»:[1]
«Приму в родство себе лакейство:
У них орехи подают
Да кислы щи в театре пьют».

Comment: Далее - рецепт, кому интересно: http://kare-l.livejournal.com/25711.html

Comment: http://kare-l.livejournal.com/25711.html

Вот классический рецепт русских кислых щей:

Всыпать в кадку 2 гарнца или 10 фунтов пшеничного солоду,

Comment: Из всего сказанного сомнительно только то, что ананасы выращивались в таких количествах, что их девать некуда было. Писавший это, видимо, плохо представлял и условия (микроклимат), требуемые для оного действия, и, главное, потребная для это площадь. Для одного растения потребно около квадратного метра площади. А плодоносит он раз в год. Разумеется, никто такой фрукт переводить на пойло не станет, особенно когда своего дармового добра навалом - от яблок до малины.

Answer (score 5):

Ко всему сказанному могу добавить (отчасти и возразить) следующее.
~1. По моей информации (к сожалению, недостоверной)  "кислые щи" отличались от обычных не только - и даже не столько способом разлива и употребления, сколько тем, что никакого отношения к капусте не имели.
~2. Готовили их вроде бы из "разнофруктов" с добавлением ягод (особенно - белой смородины) и самое главное - меда. Напиток был сродни слабой или ленивой медовухе (т.н. "медку"), но был сильнее заквашен.
~3. Самое для филолога ценное. Изготовление напитка требовало недюжинного мастерства, поэтому "профессор" изначально было совсем не ироническим. С нарушением рецептуры - исчезло и качество.
~4. Сомневаюсь, что в сети можно найти настоящий рецепт. Самое близкое - вариации на тему смородиновой медовухи. Видимо какого-то единого рецепта просто не было.

А теперь - источник основных сведений из перечисленного. 
Пятьдесят лет назад в моём дачном поселке (кому интересно - рядом с известным Переделкином) фруктовое винокурение было чуть ли не тотальным увлечением. И однин из знатоков (не только вина, языка - тоже) тогда уже более чем почтенного возраста "продал" деду рецепт этой самой смородиновой шипучки вместе с рассказом о кислых щах. Несмотря на юный возраст, я запомнил - и что мог, впоследствии проверил.
Главное: в основе всего мед, это подтверждается многими источниками.

Остальное можете рассматривать как версию.

Answer (score -1):

Мне кажется, профессор кислых щей - это алкаш.

Что-то вроде как профессор по самогону.